# Rmi server port alrady used

Tags: java, registry, port, rmi

I want to run simple rmi server code below.
Firstly, I write command "rmiregistry 9260" and so I started the rmi register.
Then I run following code but I get errors. 
What can cause these errors? Note that I tried different port numbers.

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            PaymentImpl robj = new PaymentImpl();
            Payment stub = (Payment) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(robj, 9260);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Mortgage", stub);
            System.out.println("Mortgage Server is ready to listen... ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception thrown: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Server exception thrown: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use
260; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9260; nested exception

        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Unknown Source)
        at Server.main(Server.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(
nown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(
nown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using 9260 for a separate Registry process you can't use it again in this process. You can use 9260 for both by starting the Registry in this process, with LocateRegistry.createRegistry(). Store the return value into a static variable to prevent GC.

Comment: PaymentImpl does not extend UnicastRemoteObject, it extends Remote. I tried exportObject(robj) but in this case I get java.rmi.StubNotFoundException exception..

Comment: Thanks, server side works like that. However the client cannot reach the remote object Payment. The client side is following: Registry reg =LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost"), stub = (Payment) reg.lookup("Mortgage").

Comment: And the client gets what exception?

Comment: It gets java.rmi.ConnectException

Comment: Don't feed information in dribs and drabs like that. It's like pulling teeth. Post the *entire* exception and stack trace, in your question, or start a new question.